# Using HangFire for background job processing without DB storage?

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker, webapi, hangfire

I have an ASP.NET 4.6 web API. The app does not have a standalone DB, and it is a micro-service designed for searching files. I want to implement a CRON job in the background and utilize HangFire. The problem is, seems like storage is mandatory, and `Memory Storage` is not reccomended for production.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any solution to use in production environment but a `nuget` package exists that help you to use `HangFire`, it can be useful for testing purpose like check the behavior and use it in a development environment.

- **It should not be used in production (no integrity and no thread safe
  even if many cases are managed).**
- Data are stored in memory using a dictionary in a static way (See
  Data created at the storage creation)

Source: [Hangfire.MemoryStorage](https://github.com/perrich/Hangfire.MemoryStorage)

`nuget` package : [Hangfire.MemoryStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.MemoryStorage/)

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
```

Above package can't cover in-memory jobs in production environment, but below library provided conditions that can be used in production mode:

[Hangfire.InMemory](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.InMemory)

This is an attempt to create an efficient transactional in-memory storage for `Hangfire` with data structures close to their optimal representation. The result of this attempt should enable production-ready usage of this storage implementation and handle particular properties of in-memory processing like avoiding `OutOfMemoryException` at any cost and moderate load on garbage collection. Of course we can't avoid them entirely, but at least can control them somehow.

Comment: What about this library? Seems like it is production ready? https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.InMemory

Comment: After reviewing the codes of this library, This library has provided conditions that can be used in production environment, it also covers most cases well, but you have to handle memory leak exception by yourself.
I add this nuget package with description in this answer to public use.